# How do I provide a more compact definition for the specialized template classes?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, class-template

Consider the following scenario:

```cpp
template <
    typename T,
    bool B = std::is_default_constructible_v<T>>
class toy_example;

template<typename T>
class toy_example<T, true>
{
public:
    toy_example() = default; // e.g. for default constructible types
    toy_example(const T& value);

public:
    void monomorphic(T);

private:
    T m_value;
};

template<typename T>
class toy_example<T, false> 
{
public:
    toy_example() = delete; // e.g. for non-default constructible types
    toy_example(const T& value); // Repeated declaration

public:
    void monomorphic(T); // Repeated declaration

private:
    T m_value;
};

// Implementation
template<typename T>
toy_example<T, true>::toy_example(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

// (Unnecessary?) Repetition
template<typename T>
toy_example<T, false>::toy_example(const T& value) : m_value(value) {}

template<typename T>
toy_example<T, true>::monomorphic(T) 
{
    std::cout << "Behaviour is the same despite specialisation.\n";
    // (P.S) - This is intended behaviour
}

// (Unnecessary?) Repetition
template<typename T>
toy_example<T, false>::monomorphic(T) 
{
    std::cout << "Behaviour is the same despite specialisation.\n";
    // (P.S) - This is intended behaviour
}
```

How do I provide a more compact definition for this class by providing a single definition for the functions that I want to behave in the same way (in this case, the initialization constructor and the `monomorphic` function)?

My motivation for this is that, in my codebase, the code for `monomorphic(T)` is a bit verbose and long, and I would rather not duplicate it unnecessarily.

I understand that the solution may involve using a base class of some sort, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I provide a more compact definiton for this class by providing a single definition for the functions that I want to behave in the same way (in this case, the initialisation constructor and the monomorphic function)?

Since you are using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), I would use the [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) feature, by which one could keep the both implementations to the same function body.

Additionally, the default constructor (and further common codes) can be SFINAEd for each cases in the same class.

Something along these lines.

```
class ExampleClass
{
public:
    template<typename U = T>
    ExampleClass(std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<U>>* = 0)
    {} // enabled only for default constructible types


    template<typename U = T>
    ExampleClass(
        std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible_v<U>>* = 0
    ) = delete; // For non-default constructible types

    ExampleClass(const T& value)
        : m_value{ value } {}

public:
    void monomorphic()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_default_constructible_v<T>)
        {
            std::cout << "default_constructible Impli\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Non-default_constructible Impli\n";
        }
    }

private:
    T m_value;
};
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MfqcEKqoG)

---

Alternatively, you can obviously have the common implementations in the `Base` and the derived classes (i.e. enabled/ disabled for `std::is_default_constructible_v`) can have the specialization the `monomorphic()` function, as follows:

```
// Common base class
template<typename T> class Base
{
public:
    template<typename U = T>
    Base(std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<U>>* = 0)
    {} // enabled only for default constructible types


    template<typename U = T>
    Base(std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible_v<U>>* = 0)
        = delete; // for non default constructible types

    Base(const T& value)
        : m_value{ value } {}

private:
    T m_value;
};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void> class Derived;

// specialization for true case
template<typename T>
class Derived<T, 
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible_v<T>>> 
              : public Base<T>
{
public:
    Derived() = default;
    using Base<T>::Base;
    void monomorphic(){ std::cout << "default_constructible Impli\n"; }
};

// specialization for false case
template<typename T> 
class Derived<T,
              std::enable_if_t<!std::is_default_constructible_v<T>>>
              : public Base<T>
{
public:
    using Base<T>::Base;
    void monomorphic() { std::cout << "Non-default_constructible Impli\n"; }
};
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cjnsf1q7n)

Comment: Thanks for the edits and answer. I'll try to format my question better next time :<